# Create regex from samples algorithm

Tags: regex, algorithm, pattern-matching

AFAIK no one have implemented an algorithm that takes a set of strings and substrings and gives back one or more regular expressions that would match the given substrings inside the strings. So, for instance, if I'd give my algorithm this two samples:

```
string1 = "fwef 1234 asdfd"
substring1 = "1234"

string2 = "asdf456fsdf"
substring2 = "456"
```

The algorithm would give me the regular expression "[0-9]*" back. I know it could give more than one regex or even no possible regex back and you might find 1000 reasons why such algorithm would be close to impossible to implement to perfection. But what's the closest thing?

I don't really care about regex itself also. Basically what I want is an algorithm that takes samples as the ones above and then finds a pattern in them that can be used to easily find the "kind" of text I want to find in a string without having to write any regex or code manually.

Comment: What would stop the algorithm from just producing a regular expression that is the "or" of all the possible substrings?  Or would you be comfortable with this regular expression from being produced?

Comment: That would be the dumbest algorithm ever. I would just program it such a way that it doesn't do that but tries to figure out what I really want. I know is messy though.

Comment: Or that could be just one of the many outputs. Actually this algorithm could be built by testing all possible regular expressions and outputting the ones that work. Would take a while, but I think this proves such algorithm is possible. Actually it might not take that long for simple patterns. I might try something like that.

Comment: "What I really want" is not something computers are good at. And there's an infinite number of regular expressions that produce a particular set of outputs, which is part of why your problem is poorly defined.

Comment: There is such a thing as artificial intelligence. Google is a good example of this. It tries to match what you really want and put it on the top result. Is not perfect, but pretty good. Also, if I could define my question more strictly and less subjectively, I would probably already have an answer. If you have some common sense you know what I'm looking for.

Comment: I know what you're looking for - and I know it's impractical because your problem is poorly specified. There's literally an infinite number of regular expressions that match a set of strings you provide, and no practical way for an algorithm to determine which of them is superior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlashFill a new feature of MS Excel 2013 would do exactly the task you want, but it does not give you the regular expression.  It's a NP-complete problem and an open question for practical purposes.   If you're interested in how to synthesise string manipulation from multiple examples, Go [Flash Fill official website](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/sumitg/flashfill.html) and read a few papers.  They have pseudo-code and demo. movies as well.

Comment: At least this proves that what I want can be made an algorithm and disproves what most other answers say here. I'm sure excel is using internally some kind of regex or if nothing else, something that could be translated into a regex.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have proof but I suspect no such discrete algorithm with a finite output could exist since you are asking for the creation of a regular language which could be "large" in respect to the input size.

With that, I suggest you peek at [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3) which can break down sample texts one-by-one and help you build regexes.

Answer (score 2):

There are many such algorithm in fact. This is a research area called "Grammatical inference".

I know RPNI, for example. (you could also look on the probabilistic branch, alergia, MDI, DEES). These algorithms generate DSA (Deterministic State Automata). In fact you absolutely don't need to enter the strings in your example. Only substrings.

There are also some algorithms to generate directly Non deterministic automata.

Of course, get the regular expression from an Non Deterministic Automata is easy.

The main ideas are simple:

Generate a PTSA (Prefix Tree State Automata) from your sample.

Then, you have to try to "merge" some states. From these merge, will emerge loops (i.e. * in the regular expression). All the difficulty being to choose the right rule to merge.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
re = '|'.join(substrings)
```

If you want anything more general, your algorithm is going to have to make educated guesses about what type of strings are acceptable as matches, and it's trivial to demonstrate that no procedure can account for all possible sets of possible inputs without simply enumerating them all. For instance, consider some of these scenarios:

- Match all prime numbers
- Match hexadecimal strings, but no strings containing 'f' are in the sample set
- Match the same string repeated twice
- Match any even-length string

The root problem is that your question is incompletely specified. If you have a more specific requirement, that might be solvable, depending on what it is.

Comment: how would a regexp that can match prime numbers look like?